# PHP PayPal REST API authorization call

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, paypal

I'm trying to use PHP and cURL to request an auth token from PayPal to create a payment.

my code is:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: en_US'
    ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USRPWD, 'xxxx:xxxx');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');

$output = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

I get the response:

```
curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in Users/anth/sites/abyss/auth.php on line 11
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}
```

line 11 is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USRPWD, 'xxxx:xxxx');
```

I have checked my Client ID and Secret and they are fine.

Does anyone know if I am using the wrong syntax or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USRPWD, 'xxxx:xxxx')** instead of **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'XXXX:XXXX');** . Note the missed **'E'** and apart from that you need to add one more line :
    **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);**

So the corrected version is below :

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: en_US'
    ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'XXXX:XXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($output);
```